# How to Javascript validate End time and From time with date parse with AM/PM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker, date-parsing

This is my script.

```
$(document).on("click","input[name='to_time[]']",function(){
    var from = $("input[name='from_time[]']").val(); // "11:15 AM"
    var to = $("input[name='to_time[]']").val(); //"10:15 AM"

    if(Date.parse(from) > Date.parse(to)){
      alert("Invalid Date Range");
    }
});
```

From Datepicker receiving date as this format "12:54 PM"
Date.parse(from) returning as Not a number. NaN
How do I parse this string to Javascript object or is there any alternative way to validate End time and From time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library for this. See below

```js
var from =  "11:15 AM";
var to = "10:15 AM";

if (moment(from, 'hh:mm a') > moment(to, 'hh:mm a')) {
  alert("Invalid Date Range");
} else {
  alert("Valid Date Range");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.js"></script>
```

Remember to add format `hh:mm a` while converting time string to object.